# Animation and transition timeout isn't working

Tags: css, animation, transition

Here's a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/qgchhn99/

I'm trying to delay an animation as well as a transition but it doesn't work for some reason. The animation and the opacity transition runs instantly instead of waiting 4 seconds.

I got a status message which appears when a form is submitted (the classes gets added dynamically):

```
<p class="success success--auto-hide">Some message</p>
```

Then I have this animation which will hide the element after 4 seconds:

```
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  to {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

However, I also want the hiding to be smooth so I added a transition on `opacity` as well as the hiding animation:

```
.success {
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
  transition-delay:         4s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
  transition:         opacity 4s ease-in-out;
}

.success--auto-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay:         4s;
  -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 4s forwards;
  -moz-animation:    cssAnimation 0s ease-in 4s forwards;
  -o-animation:      cssAnimation 0s ease-in 4s forwards;
  animation:         cssAnimation 0s ease-in 4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:         forwards;
}
```

I'm sure I'm close to having it correct, so how should I modify it so that both the animation and transition waits 4 seconds before it executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by increasing the animation duration from `0s` to `4s`. Having it at 0 caused the hiding animation to execute instantly, thus preventing the opacity transition to run in parallel with the animation. I also decreased the opacity duration to `3s` instead of `4s` to allow it to be completely hidden before setting the width and height to 0, which would cause the text to jump down in an oddly fashion for a split second before it became completely hidden.

I also realised that I had already set the delay in the shorthand so I could remove the `animation-delay` property altogether.

```
.success {
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
  transition-delay:         3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
  transition:         opacity 4s ease-in-out;
}

.success--auto-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 4s ease-in 4s forwards;
  -moz-animation:    cssAnimation 4s ease-in 4s forwards;
  -o-animation:      cssAnimation 4s ease-in 4s forwards;
  animation:         cssAnimation 4s ease-in 4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:         forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `.success--auto-hide` class you've already hidden the element before the animation begins, with `'opacity: 0;'`.

When you remove it, it works fine!

Also, you're giving the delay time now two times, so you can also remove the animation-delay property.

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvKjWY

Comment: I need the opacity transition to run in parallel with the animation. Because the opacity doesn't hide it, it just makes it invisible. The element should not be hidden until after 8s, it should wait 4s before starting the opacity transition, then at 8s it should be completely hidden. Your codepen doesn't achieve this.